# Synology Expansion box not visible to Rackstation

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, synology

We have two Synology Rackstation RS2418RP+'s and for a separate project we needed to add some more disk to them. We purchased a pair of RX1217RP's as according to Synology these are compatible.

I received them yesterday and set about racking and connecting them.

I've connected one box up with it's supplied connection cable and added some power to both CPU's and the box beeps, the connection light goes green and that's it. I can't see the expansion in the Synology admin console, the drives don't spin up and all I have is a green power light on the front.

I've tried connecting the second box too and this behaves exactly the same.

I've reported the issue with Synology tech support and so far the best they've come up with is that I should test both sets of hard drives individually using the manufacturers test tools!
To say I'm un-impressed is an understatement.

Anyone experienced this and have any tips for what I can try next ?

Comment: Unimpressed as you may be with their support, have you done what they suggested? "My doctor said that I should be taking vitamins, but I'm unimpressed with his advice".

Comment: well it's not quite the same thing. If 24 hard drives have all decided to stop working at the same time, the two expansion boxes should still be visible in the synology with or without disks (and they aren't)... so no I've not removed the hard drives and found a usb caddy and plugged them in, since I'm 99.9% sure this isn't the issue

Comment: Understood. My point is that they're probably going to be reticent to provide more in depth support if you don't do as they ask. "Did you test the hard drives individually?" - "No." - "Well do that first and then call us back."

Comment: Yeah I get your point, however we didn't purchase the hard drives separately, we bought a 48TB expansion box and it's unlikely that 24 hard drives would all be faulty and DOA unless something catastrophic happened to both boxes or weren't correctly constructed by whoever constructed them... having explained that it is ridiculous for him to suggest that not only are both boxes faulty and both sets of disks are also faulty, he conceded that was correct. I'm in the process of updating the main rackstation and rebooting it as per my original suggestion, we'll see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Right having finally freed up the rackstation from the backup server, I upgraded the Rackstation OS and it rebooted itself... I can now see the RX1217 in storage manager.

So to my original question for Synology support... do I need to reboot this for it to see the disks? Err YES!

Good old turn it off turn it on saves the day !